# netstat: illegal option -- o when using netstat -ano in MacOS

Tags: macos, netstat

I want to list all PID with its state and foreign address.

But I got this error:

```
netstat: illegal option -- o
```

So how to do that in MacOS? It works on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the corresponding ProcessID (pid) - you can use `netstat -v`
-v (verbose) and that will give you the pid of the foreign addresses, and their pid.